# What is an elegant way in Ruby to tell if a variable is a Hash or an Array?

Tags: ruby, arrays, hash

To check what `@some_var` is, I am doing a

```
if @some_var.class.to_s == 'Hash'
```

I am sure that there is a more elegant way to check if `@some_var` is a `Hash` or an `Array`.

Comment: Andrew: I am calling an API and in the JSON I get back, if there are multiple results I get an Array but if there is only one I get a Hash rather than a single element Array. Is there a better forward than doing the Array vs Hash check?

Comment: So you get either `[result_hash, another_result_hash]` or `single_result_hash`? Whoever created that API wasn't doing a good job!

Comment: You’re right, Andrew, and I bet it’s *a lot* easier to get the people who wrote the API to fix it than to test for a hash versus an array.

Comment: i have the same situation as @drhyde. In my case the 3rd party is HTTParty which after parsing an XML file has no way to decide what is the best way to handle a situation where an element can have 1-n children.

Comment: You should watch Avdi Grimms screencast: https://www.rubytapas.com/2016/10/17/episode-451-advanced-class-membership and probably make cabos answer the accepted one.

Answer (score 310, accepted):

You can just do:

```
@some_var.class == Hash
```

or also something like:

```
@some_var.is_a?(Hash)
```

It's worth noting that the "is_a?" method is true if the class is anywhere in the objects ancestry tree. for instance:

```
@some_var.is_a?(Object)  # => true
```

the above is true if @some_var is an instance of a hash or other class that stems from Object. So, if you want a strict match on the class type, using the == or instance_of? method is probably what you're looking for.

Comment: `is_a?` is the best option, since it also returns `true` for subclasses.

Comment: And, of course, you also leave out the brackets, so `@som_var.is_a? Hash` works too :)

Comment: Be careful, this could really screw you if someone ends up passing you an instance of ActiveSupport::HashWithIndifferentAccess.  Which responds like a hash, but is not in fact a Hash.  :(

Comment: I'd also have liked more answers going into detail regarding duck-typing, since the original author apparently was looking for a ruby way of doing a type check.

Comment: @unflores `ActiveSupport::HashWithIndifferentAccess` inherits from Hash, hence `@some_var.is_a?(Hash)` will return true in this case as well. (I just had the same question and HashWithIndifferentAccess case and got a bit confused from your comment...so I wanted to clarify)

Comment: @NobodysNightmare - I don't know if there's a 'Ruby way' of doing a type check.  You should strive to eliminate type checks in object-oriented languages, I've been learning.  External APIs are definitely tricky.

Comment: I've also had issues with using this method in `case` statments. Seemed to only work for me in `if..else` statements.

Comment: Rubocop seems to prefer `instance_of?(Hash)`

Answer (score 46):

First of all, the best answer for the literal question is

```
Hash === @some_var
```

But the question really should have been answered by showing how to do duck-typing here.
That depends a bit on what kind of duck you need.

```
@some_var.respond_to?(:each_pair)
```

or

```
@some_var.respond_to?(:has_key?)
```

or even

```
@some_var.respond_to?(:to_hash)
```

may be right depending on the application.

Answer (score 26):

Usually in ruby when you are looking for "type" you are actually wanting the "duck-type" or "does is quack like a duck?".  You would see if it responds to a certain method:

```
@some_var.respond_to?(:each)
```

You can iterate over @some_var because it responds to :each

If you really want to know the type and if it is Hash or Array then you can do:

```
["Hash", "Array"].include?(@some_var.class)  #=> check both through instance class
@some_var.kind_of?(Hash)    #=> to check each at once
@some_var.is_a?(Array)   #=> same as kind_of
```

Comment: This won't work if your code is dependent on the ordering of the data(e.g. if you are using each_with_index). The order of the elements is implemented differently between hashes and arrays and it is different between ruby versions.(http://intertwingly.net/slides/2008/oscon/ruby19/22)

Comment: @juan2raid: If order is important, then call `sort` on it first.

Comment: @Brandon second example should convert the class to string.<br/>`["Hash", "Array"].include?(@some_var.class.to_s) #=> check both through instance class`

Answer (score 15):

```
Hash === @some_var #=> return Boolean
```

this can also be used with case statement

```
case @some_var
when Hash
   ...
when Array
   ...
end
```

Answer (score 5):

I use this:

```
@var.respond_to?(:keys)
```

It works for Hash and ActiveSupport::HashWithIndifferentAccess.

Answer (score 4):

You can use `instance_of?`

e.g

```
@some_var.instance_of?(Hash)
```

Comment: Note that this does not work for *subclasses*! For example, if you have an `ActiveRecord::Collection` and try `instance_of?(Array)` then this will return `false`, whereas `is_a?(Array)` will return `true`.

Answer (score 4):

In practice, you will often want to act differently depending on whether a variable is an Array or a Hash, not just mere tell. In this situation, an *elegant* idiom is the following:

```
case item
  when Array
   #do something
  when Hash
   #do something else
end
```

Note that you don't call the `.class` method on `item`.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to test if an object is strictly or extends a `Hash`, use:

```
value = {}
value.is_a?(Hash) || value.is_a?(Array) #=> true
```

But to make value of Ruby's duck typing, you could do something like:

```
value = {}
value.respond_to?(:[]) #=> true
```

It is useful when you only want to access some value using the `value[:key]` syntax.

> Please note that `Array.new["key"]` will raise a `TypeError`.

Answer (score -2):

```
irb(main):005:0> {}.class
=> Hash
irb(main):006:0> [].class
=> Array
```