# How to determine if the contents of a text field are a hash or a string in rails using ruby?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3.1

I have a field defined as text (on the database side) in my rails application.  Now, some of the older data was written directly to it as string.  I want to start adding hashes to it.

When I retrieve the data, I want to render it differently if it is a Hash.

Here is what I have tried and it does not work because the acts_like? method is always returning false:

```
if suggestion.acts_like? Hash
  suggestion.each {|attr, value| puts(helper.t attr+": "+value.to_s)}
else
  puts suggestion
end
```

What am I doing incorrectly? Is acts_like? even the right thing to use here?

---

I had tried to close out the question as I found an answer for it but it seems it did not save properly.

Here is what I ended up using:

```
if suggestion.is_a? Hash
....
else
...
end
```

I still don't know why acts_like? won't work but is_a? does work! Oldergod's suggestion of kind_of? works too!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5367114/what-is-a-simple-elegant-way-in-ruby-to-tell-if-a-particular-variable-is-a-has

Comment: What do you mean by "adding hashes to it"? How are you planning to serialize your hashes? Converting all the existing data to your new format would be best plan.

Comment: @muistooshort - it is actually part of another Hash (serialize :feedback, Hash)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could

```
if suggestion.kind_of?(Hash)
  # ...
end
```

or

```
if Hash === suggestion
  # ...
end
```

Comment: Yes this and is_a? both work.  Any idea why acts_like? does not work?  Rails documentation lists that as duck typing check method.

Comment: the source code shows it returns respond_to? :"acts_like_#{duck}?" so I guess the acts_like_Hash? is not defined for the hash object ?